# XSLT: Losing xmlns attributes from copied nodes, where that attribute is previously defined by an ancestor?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

When copying nodes and attributes using XSLT, I'm losing xmlns attribute values when those attributes have been previously defined by an ancestor node.

The attribute definition on the descendant is redundant, functionally, since it's already been set by the ancestor.  (Correct me if I'm wrong on that point.)  Presumably this redundancy is why the attribute is not being written when the descendant is being created, but I can't find anything to confirm that.

Is there a way to retain the duplicated/redundant xmlns attributes for those descendants?

Operating Environment:

- openjdk 11.0.19 2023-04-18
- Ubuntu 22.04
- Saxon HE 11.5

The XSLT, a simple Identity Transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example input XML, in which 4 attributes (`xmlns:oai_qdc`, `xmlns:dc`, `xmlns:dcterms`, `xmlns:xsi`) are duplicated between the ancestor `OAI-PMH` and descendant `oai_qdc:qualifieddc` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:oai_qdc="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc-1.0/"
         xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
  <ListRecords>
    <record>
      <header>
        <datestamp>1998-07-05T07:00:00Z</datestamp>
      </header>
      <metadata>
        <oai_qdc:qualifieddc xmlns:oai_qdc="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc-1.0/" 
                             xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
                             xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
                             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                             xsi:schemaLocation="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc-1.0/ http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc/1.0/qdc-1.0.xsd">
          <dc:title>Some Title</dc:title>
        </oai_qdc:qualifieddc>
      </metadata>
    </record>
  </ListRecords>
</OAI-PMH>
```

Output from the transform, in which the 4 duplicated attributes are no longer displayed on the descendant `oai_qdc:qualifieddc` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" 
         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
         xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
         xmlns:oai_qdc="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc-1.0/"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
  <ListRecords>
    <record>
      <header>
        <datestamp>1998-07-05T07:00:00Z</datestamp>
      </header>
      <metadata>
        <oai_qdc:qualifieddc xsi:schemaLocation="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc-1.0/ http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/qdc/1.0/qdc-1.0.xsd">
          <dc:title>Some Title</dc:title>
        </oai_qdc:qualifieddc>
      </metadata>
    </record>
  </ListRecords>
</OAI-PMH>
```

Answer (score -1):

Whatever you call attributes, they are in reality namespaces.

And yes, they they are redundant anywhere outside of the root node. Every single element below root node is bound to the same namespaces.

Additionally, Saxon HE 11.5 supports XSLT 3.0

So, your XSLT with the *Identity Transform* pattern could be reduced to one liner as follows:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"
                omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform pattern-->
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To copy all relevant namespaces, please try the following XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"
                omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform pattern-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your response does not answer my fundamental question:  Is there a way to retain the duplicated/redundant xmlns attributes for those descendants?